# Session Variable not comparing with other variables

Tags: php

I've been learning php for a little while now and I'm having a go at using sessions... I thought I was doing quite well until I hit a wall and what I'm trying to do I would have thought would be very simple but I'm really struggling so hope someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong! I have set $user = $_SESSION variable at login level and if I echo $user on the next page, I do see the name of the user.I thought that $user would now store the name as a string but when I try...

if($user !== $name1 || $name2) {echo 'error message';}
i.e. if $user is not equal to one name or the other , I want to throw an error message. I have tried restructuring this in so many ways but to no avail. Have I perhaps misunderstood the method of comparing a session variable with other variables?! Perhaps I should consider a different function?Thanks,Alex

Comment: Show your actual code

Comment: You can't just `if($user !== $name1 || $name2) {echo 'error message';}`, you would need to run `if($user !== $name1 && $user !== $name2) {echo 'error message';}`. Just a guess though, please show your code so that we may help you.

Comment: Guys, sorry for not adding full code, will bear that in mind next time! Dave... this did work perfectly! Actually I'm kicking myself for not thinking of structuring my if statement that way in the first place! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

"$user = $_SESSION variable at login level and if I echo $user on the next page,"

Your $user variable has most likely died during the page refresh, that is, on your next page. 
You must access the session variable every time you're on a new page.

I need to see more code to give a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond... the variable didn't die but I did structure the if statement incorrectly! Problem now resolved!